# How to make Shadows-Only Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light, shadows

How can I achieve the following effect? Here, we see all shadows, and nothing else.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Image:*

[image]

*Stylized shadow only pass:*

[image]

### Preparations

- Go to the *Properties panel > Render tab > Film dropdown* and check *Transparent*.
- Go to the *Properties panel > Render Layers tab > Passes dropdown* and enable the *Shadow* pass.

### Compositing

You should be able to achieve it with the following compositing nodes setup. What it does is takes the *Alpha* pass (where there is stuff (white) versus where there is transparency (black)) and subtracts all the white areas (unshadowed parts) of the shadow pass. This does, however, need to be inverted to look correct.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems the OP is using the Cycles render engine, not BI.

Comment: @PGmath That is cycles.

Comment: Oh sorry, I guess I can't distinguish it too well on my phone. :D

Comment: @PGmath I feel you. Plus, the shading does look a lot like BI. That was actually one of the things I tried to change, but it just didn't work out and I didn't want to put a lot of time into it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer!  Can you please add the .blend file to marked as the answer?

Comment: @AlexSafayan Included! If my answer helped, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 15):

While [Shady Puck's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58755/5705) covers making a true shadow-only render, here is my approach to creating this type of render using the Cycles Toon shader in combination with a shadow pass and some manual contrast adjustment.

My final result:

[image]
*Thanks to [MrChimp2313](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/74114) for the awesome CC-0 house model!*

---

First just give everything a white *Toon* shader material, this will help with that contrasty, cartoony look.  The Toon shader also has two other properties (besides color), you should set the *Size* to something fairly high (close to `1.0`) and leave the *Smooth* at `0.0`.

Light the scene with a single sun lamp, with a fairly small shadow size.  Tweak the direction and strength to suit your tastes for your scene.

Set the environment color to Black, this way the shadows and highlights will all come from the sun lamp.

Make sure to turn on the *Shadow* render pass and render your image.  Keep in mind that for this effect to work you need to eliminate as much noise as possible, so use a *lot* of samples.

In the compositor, run the shadow pass image itself through a *Color Ramp* node.  You can tweak the swatches' positions to get the effect you are looking for, but the basic idea is to have them fairly close together to get that super high-contrast shadowy look.  I also found it looks a little more pleasing if you adjust the minimum color to be not pure black.

[image]

Comment: Oops, in the compositing setup the *Shadow* pass should be plugged into the Color Ramp, not the *Image*.  I'll fix that soon.