# How can I achieve this inked sketch material?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, npr

Let me preface this by saying that I'm a complete beginner when it comes to Blender, as in - I just clicked on the Blender icon for the very first time ever yesterday.

I'm trying to achieve an inked sketch material. I've created one that I'm 90% satisfied with already (Principled BSDF>Shader to RGB>Color Ramp>Material Output). This is the result:
[image]

(BTW, model was not done in Blender but in Sketchup. I'm not *that* quick of a learner :)

So, I'm just looking to add a little bit of roughness/pen strokes to the material. [This blender material](http://matrep.parastudios.de/index.php?action=view&material=793-inked-sketch) looks exactly like what I'm trying to achieve, but after downloading it I can neither open, nor link/append it for some reason (I'm using Blender 2.81 and 2.77, didn't work with either).

I'm thinking some kind of procedural wood texture added as a bump map and somehow occluded to appear only at the edge of the black and white areas would do the trick, but I don't know how to do that.

BTW, I've looked at a few tutorials online for toon/sketched materials, but none of them are what I'm looking for. They are either too cartoonish, or the inking is too heavy and unrealistic.

Thanks in advance to anyone who could help me out with this!

Comment: The key to creating this type of shader is using the ramp node. This [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4Wj12NPkHA) shows the solution with the Blender render. However, you can replicate the method for Cycle Render as well. Moreover, you can achieve more plastic colors like a rainbow or etc.

Comment: I believe adding a noise node with the Y-axis severely downscaled (like .001) and then adding that to the ramp mapping with either multiply or screen in a mix node will achieve the effect you're after. If you share your blend file, I could be more specific.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33871/is-there-really-a-way-to-make-a-true-toon-shader-material-in-cycles/33880#33880 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159028/scientific-illustration-non-photorealistic-rendering-of-sparse-wireframe-with-d/159038#159038 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10925/how-to-render-cartoon-style-with-completely-flat-colors https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2034/can-cycles-do-a-gooch-shader https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58752/how-to-make-shadows-only-render/58775#58775

Comment: @PJM Design, thank you for your suggestion, I'll give it a go. Here's the blend file of the model I'm working on: [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17g78ykyU3dFxsubqvNKnRR9EE-KB1T14/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Xayzer, here is what I was talking about, obviously more involved than just the noise node, but tweak it as you desire. [File](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvzIETDAN_0GnpE1bX5rXiFyRExLgQ?e=Dj4z41)  |  [Screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvzIETDAN_0GnpE0XRCOcA89ebVF9Q?e=FhD218)

Comment: @PJM Design, thank you so very much for taking the time to do this, I really appreciate it. I think you've set me on the right path!

Comment: @Xayzer, My pleasure ;)